# The *compressive* strength of spider silk

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, material-science, biophysics, biology

There's plenty of information about the [tensile strength](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02396800), [density](https://www.surfacesreporter.com/articles/10530/spider-silk-fibre-with-unbelievable-strength), [energy density](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fchem.2020.00554/full), [ductility](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2658765/), etc. of [spider silk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider_silk).

However, I personally cannot find any figures in regards to the [*compressive strength*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compressive_strength) of spider silk - i.e. how much inwards force it can withstand per unit of surface area before deforming.

Does anyone have any sources on the compressive strength of spider silk?

Answer (score 1):

The best estimate of the compressive strength of spider silk **material** (i.e., the hierarchical protein structure of mostly [spidroin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spidroin)) is its tensile strength. That is, for either uniaxial pulling or pushing, the common failure mode tends to be shear of [β-sheet nanocrystals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider_silk#Macroscopic_structure_down_to_protein_hierarchy). Therefore, it's reasonable as a first pass to assume symmetry between tension and compression strength.

Unfortunately, I haven't found direct corresponding experimental results, e.g., nanoindentation hardness results. However, Bai et al. in "[Regenerated spider silk as a new biomaterial for MEMS](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10544-006-9820-x)" discuss the hardness (in the hundreds of MPa) of various compositions of thin films of reconstituted spider silk.

As noted in the comments, the compressive strength of macroscale spider silk **threads** is essentially zero because their narrow diameter results in immediate buckling.

Answer (score 0):

The question is how one can measure compressive strength of thin fibers. It turns out there are some methods to do that, e.g., the so-called "tension recoil" method. This method was used in [Arch. Mech., 65, 1, pp. 27–43, Warszawa 2013](http://home.iitk.ac.in/%7Emohite/axial_compressive.pdf) for carbon fibers. They measured the compressive strength of their fibers to be 869 MPa, whereas the tensile strength of those fibers was 3.02 GPa. I did not find similar data for spider silk, but maybe it would be reasonable to hypothesize that its compressive strength is also about 1/3 of its tensile strength.